# Does Azure Functions work over HTTPS?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

So the question is simple, does Azure Functions work over HTTPS or they using only HTTP? Can't find such notes in the documentations. I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Lots of the documentation/examples/demos has https....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Functions definitely support HTTPS. If you create an HTTP triggered function, and then click the "Get function URL" button you will see a URL like

```
https://myawesomefunctions.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTriggerCSharp1
```

Behind the scenes Function App is running on Web App, so you should be able to configure HTTPS with your custom domain, in case you need to expose the endpoints with nicer domain.

Comment: Thank you. Lost this simple thing.